# Formula for Variance influence % vs Total Variance

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the below table:

```
           Q1 Price Q2 Price    Variance    Q2 Sales
Overall     53.08   46.57       -6.51        4101
Product 1   49.55   43.01       -6.54        3262
Product 2   50.00   40.93       -9.07        608
Product 3   50.00   50.00        0.00        174
Product 4   300.00  300.00       0.00        57
```

I want to create a new column '%' that shows how much each individual product price variance (Product 1-4 rows) influences the overall variance of -6.51. For example, what % of -9.07 variance for Product 2 is influencing the overall variance of -6.51.

I tried to use SUMPRODUCT() but am not getting the desired output.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Both the change in price and the change in sales affect the overall (weighted average) price variance though, right?

Comment: Please share the math. formula an the expected output. It is not clear to me what do you want to accomplish in excel. There are many ways to define variance. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidLeal - if the table begins in cell A1, then `=SUMPRODUCT(C3:C6,E3:E6)/E2` returns the Q2 Overall Price. i.e. it's a weighted average price. Variance is just Q2 Price - Q1 Price. Though I agree, OP needs to add more detail.

Comment: Apologies, I should have provided more context. @DavidLeal has provided the correct logic. ```=SUMPRODUCT(C3:C6,E3:E6)/E2``` gets the overall so ```=SUMPRODUCT(C3,E3)/$E$2``` and so will get me the individual WA price. So from there I can easily calculate the percentage, thanks!